# Trouble training recognizer in the example code in Keras_OCR docs

Tags: python, keras, ocr

While attempting to train the recognizer, the code throws a ValueError for a reason I can't spot.

I'm currently trying to get a feel for training OCR models and I've worked through a couple errors with Keras_OCR's example code [here](https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/end_to_end_training.html) but I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I'm getting the error below, which I believe to mean that my image generators are trying to pass in some sort of None value, but after looking through all the generators used, they all seem to be fine. I am using a custom alphabet and a custom text generator, but I didn't get this error while training the detector in the same code.

The recognizer's fit function is below,

```js
recognizer.training_model.fit(
    x=recognition_train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(len(background_splits[0]) / recognition_batch_size),
    epochs=1000,
    workers=0,
    callbacks=[
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(restore_best_weights=True, patience=25),
        tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(f'{recognizer_basepath}.csv', append=True),
        tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=f'{recognizer_basepath}.h5')
    ],
    validation_data=recognition_val_generator,
    validation_steps=math.ceil(len(background_splits[1]) / recognition_batch_size),
    batch_size=recognition_batch_size,
)
```

and the error thrown is here

```py
    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lambda_1' (type Lambda).

    None values not supported.

    Call arguments received by layer 'lambda_1' (type Lambda):
      • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 6), dtype=float32)']
      • mask=None
      • training=True
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Did you ever get past this?

Comment: @Scott hate to say it but nope.